# Launcher icon got invisible on Ubuntu 12.04 after last update on Jan. 1th 2017

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher, compiz, icons

After installing the ubuntu updates (2017-01-01) I can't see the icons in launcher bar. Also when I use the alt-tab for task switch this window is transparent too.

Interesting: launcher and task switch works fine and I could find the transparent buttons by their help strings.

1. action: I try to call:
   unity --reset-icons    result: it hangs in: Setting Update "run_key", only a logout could get it out
2. action: I try to call:
   unity --reset    same result: it hangs in: Setting Update "run_key",  only a logout could get it out
3. action: I try to reinstall compiz and unity:
   result: after reboot same issue.
4. action 
   call: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
   here everything seems to be ok. (see log: /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p)
5. action 
   repeat call unity --reset    same result as before (see log: unity --reset)

I put all collected logs into linked file see [unity-errors.txt](http://ib-kraft.net/unity-errors.txt)

Now I'm at the end of my ideas.

Who can help me to get the icons back?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The icons came back after last update - please see list of updates

Comment: > nvidia-304:amd64 (304.132-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 304.134-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), 
> nvidia-331:amd64 (340.98-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 340.101-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), 
> nvidia-340:amd64 (340.98-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 340.101-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), 
> nvidia-304-updates:amd64 (304.132-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 304.134-0ubuntu0.12.04.1), 
> nvidia-340-uvm:amd64 (340.98-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, 340.101-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)

Here I guess that the problem is related to nvidia driver, after that update everything works fine again.